# coordinate change differential equation polar

Tags: polarization, coordinate-systems, differential-equations

**I noticed that `v` [in step (2.5)] is not the same as the terms from the first formula, even if they are related..**

**I tried to understand how did he reach to this step:**

[image]

**I got a link ([is found here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=yfY2uGROVrUC&lpg=PA68&ots=dXVwlKChs6&dq=coordinate%20change%20differential%20equation%20polar&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=coordinate%20change%20differential%20equation%20polar&f=false)) and still didn't understand the passing to (2.5). please help me to understand it.**

**any help appreciated!**

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61289/2451

Comment: I know but here I'm just asking for the step (2.5).

Comment: Equation (2.5) expresses the velocity field in function of the stream function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function